# CSS unable to force image width and height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a panoramic image with a specific size and a hidden overflow to eventually enable user-induced panning (the code is not included below).

I'm adding the image this way:

```
<div class="pan">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/sports-q-c-1920-480-7.jpg">
</div>
```

I am setting the image size parameters this way:

```
.pan {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red solid;
}
```

However, when I change the width, the height changes proportionally, and I don't have any overflow to hide. The image is 13632 × 2936.

This is the result I get from the code above:

[image]

When setting the size this way, I get the image below:

```
.pan {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red solid;
}
```

[image]

Trying to override img parameters set to 100% (for other purposes), I get a distorted image--still no hidden overflow:

```
.pan img {
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
  transition: opacity .6s linear .8s;
}
```

[image]

Other code related to .pan and a container (from tutorial cited below) :

```
.pan img{
  transition: opacity .6s linear .8s;
}

.pan img.loaded{ opacity: 1; }

.img-pan-container, .img-pan-container img{ -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }

.img-pan-container{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: crosshair;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-pan-container img{
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); -ms-transform: translateZ(0); transform: translateZ(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

*For info*, I am trying to implement this [example](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning/). However, I am not currently focusing my question on the rest of the panning code, as I am having issues just getting the image sized correctly with the hidden overflow.

Comment: Setting overflow to hidden doesn't allow user-induced panning, it just hides the area outside of your set dimensions. Setting the image size with overflow set to hidden will basically 'crop' your image to the dimensions you set (which works for me when I test your code.)

Comment: @Tim Troiano The user-induced panning is elsewhere in the code. This is just a pre-curser to the panning, that I would like to set but am unable to do.

Comment: looks like a matter of different ratio box/image. if image is set to width:100%, the result is okay.  the code shown clips the image : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXQbKG  check your snippets :)

Comment: @user25976 are you trying to get image cover effect here? like `background-size: cover`

Comment: @350D I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to dippas' first code snippet. The effect I'm eventually trying to get is here: http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-image-panning/demo/demo-no-tween.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `img` child has to be larger than the parent `.pan`, see snippet below with an image of 1920px `width` and 480px `height`. But this will crop parts of the image.

#### Snippet

```css
.pan {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red solid /* demo */
}
img {
  display:block /* fix inline gap */
}
```

```html
<div class="pan">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question, it is most likely you have in your css `img` set as `max-width:100%`, see the same snippet above with that property set.

#### Snippet

```css
.pan {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red solid /* demo */
}
img {
  display:block; /* fix inline gap */
  max-width:100% /* YOUR ISSUE */  
}
```

```html
<div class="pan">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE** OP's Comment:

> This may be the case...How can I override `img` for only this class?

If you can't find the origin and/or want to keep the `max-width:100%` for other `img`s you can override by using `max-width:none` on `.pan > img`

```css
.pan {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: red solid  /* demo */
}
img {
  display: block;  /* fix inline gap */
  max-width: 100%  /* YOUR ISSUE */
}
.pan > img {
  max-width: none
}
```

```html
<div class="pan">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/480/" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the issue is related to the size of my image? My image is 13632 × 2936

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean when you say  user-induced panning, can you explain me that? So i can better help you. And does my snippet do what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In terms of your hidden overflow parameter, yes. In terms of panning, no--but I suppose this question was not focused on this part of the code. I am trying to implement this: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning/

Comment: And what can't you implement? you should give a snippet of what you are tryng to implement, JS included.  but here is a [demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/jquery-image-panning/demo/demo-no-tween.html) from the link you gave me

Comment: I haven't gotten to the JS yet, as only the CSS is giving me issues. For the moment, I have not modified the JS from the tutorial, except for the class name .pan. I added an image of what I am getting from your suggestion to add a border to see actual result.

Comment: This may be the case...How can I override img for only this class?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to archive cover effect for image using this css:

```
.pan {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/350D/18wz9sro/)